# How do i write this in cout/c++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, cout

How do i write the following function with cout? My main purpose is to actually print all the values to a file after i know how to use it with cout. std::hex does not work!

```
void print_hex(unsigned char *bs, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", bs[i]);
        //Below does not work
        //std::cout << std::hex << bs[i];
    }

}
```

---

edit:

cout print out values such as : r9{èZ[¶ôÃ

Comment: "Does not work" is useless as diagnostic information.  What does it do, and how does this differ from what you expected it to do?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work". What happens when you try to use `std::hex`?

Comment: Does it work if you add << endl; ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think adding a cast to int will do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void print_hex(unsigned char *bs, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(bs[i]);
    }

}

int main() {
  unsigned char bytes[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
  print_hex(bytes, sizeof bytes);
}
```

This is needed to force it to print as a number, not a character which is what you were seeing.

Comment: It may be necessary instead to do `std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex` to get the desired behavior for integers less than 16.

Comment: @dupdupdup: So check it as the accepted answer. Flexo'll probably appreciate the reputation more than the thanks (though both are nice), and any future person who comes here looking for an answer to this question will *really* appreciate having it marked off.

Comment: @DragoonWraith for your info, there is a time lapse to check it. and i do check the answer for all my questions. :)

Comment: @dupdupdup: I forgot about that; figured you'd just forgotten. Sorry then.